# WebRTC record both myself and caller

Tags: javascript, webrtc, record

I am trying to figure how would I record one on one video chat using webrtc and place it locally on receivers computer?

I am well aware that the server doesn't know anything about our call, but the client does so I think it would be possible to record both users on the client side.

Any pointers where I should go too look for info? and is this even possible?

Comment: You could lazily screencap the call on one of the clients with [OBS](https://obsproject.com/).

Answer (score 1):

You may want to checkout [MediaRecorder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder)

Personally I did not record a webRTC Chat yet, but I recorded my webcam with that. It should work for the stream as well.

Comment: Yes, it will work. Tested it many times. There are also many wrappers around it. You just need to pass a media stream into it to record

Comment: @Rubycon, Thats what I thought. A videostream is a videostream... :-)